# a JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again and A java exception has ocurred error after exporting the program in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

After exporting the program, when I try to run the JAR file, the error occurs:
a JNI error occurred, check your installation and try again followed by a java exception occurred.
I have no idea how to solve this, I don't know if it's something about the code or the Java version
I'll post the code here (the main code) so please help!

My java is: 8 281 as JDK

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable, KeyListener{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int WIDTH = 160;
    public static int HEIGHT = 120;
    public static int SCALE = 3;
    
    public BufferedImage layer = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    
    public static Enemy enemy;
    public static Player player;
    public static Ball ball;
    
    public Game() {
        
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        player = new Player(60, HEIGHT-5);
        enemy = new Enemy(60, 0);
        ball = new Ball(60, HEIGHT/2 - 1);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Game game = new Game();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong by Skubs");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        new Thread(game).start();
    }
    
    public void tick() {
        player.tick();
        enemy.tick();
        ball.tick();
    }
    
    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        
        Graphics g = layer.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0 , WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 60 , WIDTH, HEIGHT/120);
    
        
        player.render(g);
        enemy.render(g);
        ball.render(g);
        
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(layer, 0, 0, WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE, null);
        
        bs.show();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        requestFocus();
        while(true) {
            tick();
            render();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000/60);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        
    }
        
    

  
    
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
              player.right = true;  
              
        }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            player.left = true;
        }
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
              player.right = false; 
              
        }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            player.left = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}

    enter code here
```

Comment: Generally this is due to a platform specific library not being installed (e.g. for awt or swing in this case).  Thank you for the code, but in this case the exception stack itself would be more helpful.

Comment: How do i instal this swing in the platform library?

Comment: Generally it comes with the JDK, so if you're seeing these kinds of errors it is an indicator there is something up with your installation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/compile.html